# Calculate numbers inside view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add numbers from a loop inside MVC view and display the total value of those numbers. But the code bellow is just adding numbers one beside another not getting calculated. Can you plz tell me how can i make it to calculate all number and display?

```
@{ var TotalWatch = ""; }
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.tableItems)
{
 if (item.NumberOfWatch != "")
 {
     TotalWatch += item.NumberOfWatch;
 }
}
@TotalWatch
```

Comment: TotalWatch is a string, what happens when you use `+` with strings...?  If you intend to perform some _arithmetic_ then you need to use types that are _numbers_ (ie int)

Comment: Change to `var TotalWatch = 0;`. If `item.NumberOfWatch` is a `string` type storing numeric value, you need to convert it to int before adding.

Comment: Why can't you just use `.Sum()` on the collection you want to sum?  Something like: `ViewBag.tableItems.Sum(i => i.NumberOfWatch)`  Or expose a calculated property on your model and simply bind the view to that property?  Any time you have to declare a variable in your view, you're probably doing something wrong.  Just bind to the data that's in your model.

Comment: and use the correct types. Use numeric type to store numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `item.NumberOfWatch` is a string, the following should work, but is a bad approach.

```
@{ var TotalWatch = 0; }
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.tableItems)
{
 if (item.NumberOfWatch != "")
 {
     TotalWatch += int.Parse(item.NumberOfWatch);
 }
}
@TotalWatch
```

Instead, you should have a strongly-typed view model, which should be passed to the View, rather than passing data through `ViewBag`.

e.g.

Your model:

```
class YourViewModel
  int TotalWatch // sum it here
```

Your view:

```
@Model.TotalWatch
```

Comment: `int.Parse` is `Int32.Parse`. @JohnLk, you are missing the `int.Parse`

Comment: This worked thanks. Can you also plz tell me @{TotalWatch * 100;} how can i do 100 multiply with it?